# ImportError:numpy.core.multiarray failed to import when use pytorch

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

When I import `torch` in *cmd* window I get the error :

```
ImportError:numpy.core.multiarray failed to import' after using pyinstaller.
```

I tried `numpy` `1.18.4`, `1.18.3` and `1.16.3.` but it still doesn't work.

By the way, I use Windows 10, `anaconda`, Python 3.6 and `torch` 1.5.0.

Thank you for your advice.

```
File ''site-packages\torch\__init__.py'',line 136 in <module>
ImportError:numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

Comment: Does https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/559 help, i.e. uninstalling old versions of Numpy?

Comment: thank you.I use virtual environment in anaconda.There are several environments work for different projiect.You mean all numpy versions should be same even though they are in different environments?